Convert FromSqlRaw List Items to String Type
I am very new to learning APS.NET Core Web API and I am having trouble with a result I am getting from a stored procedure I am running using FromSqlRaw
I have a class for input:
public class DevInput
{
   public string DevID { get; set;}
   public int Source { get; set;}
}

and I have a class for output:
public class DevOutput
{
   public string Name{ get; set;}
   public string Cost { get; set; }
   public string OrdQty { get; set;}
   public string Model { get; set}
}

I am mapping the return from a SQL stored procedure to said class with:
public class DevOutputController : ControlleBase
{
   private readonly DevContext _context;

   public DevOutputContoller(DevContext context)
   {
      _context = context
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<DevOutput>>> GetOutput(DevInput input)
   {
      string sp = "Exec DevSearch '" + input.DevID + "', " + input.Source + ""
   
      return await _context.DevOutput.FromSqlRaw(sp).ToListAsync
   }
}

This is working fine except sometimes the "Cost" returned from the stored procedure is a decimal type, and sometimes a string type depending on what sql table the "Cost" value is retrieved from
I am wondering if there is a way that I can convert whatever is returned from the stored procedure to a string so that it can properly be mapped to my output class

Can you perform this conversion in the stored procedure itself, so that the returned result always has consistent typing?

Thanks @David the stored procedure is doing cast((case statement) as nvarchar(100)) as "Cost" I have confirmed that the "Cost" value is what I am having an issue with. Not sure why this isn't working

In that case what's the actual issue?  Where/how does the code shown fail?  (Aside from the fact that it won't compile...)

The error I am getting is System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.String'. When I try to run the stored procedure when the input.source is 0 (the case statement selects cost from a different table based on the source value) it works fine when the value is 1 but bombs when it is 0. I have tried commenting out the "cost" value for the class and confirmed everything else works in either case. It is specifically an issue with the returned "Cost". The error says the issue occurs here: return await _context.DevOutput.FromSqlRaw(sp).ToListAsync

It sounds like the stored procedure is returning a decimal value where you expect a string value.  Though you claim you've already checked and confirmed that this is not the case?  Can you include the stored procedure and relevant table definitions as a [mcve] of the problem?

Hopefully you are not doing this from UI input "Exec DevSearch '" + input.DevID so if I accidently enter "'; drop table customers;" you are safe

I would strongly recommend that you fix the stored procedure to return consistent column types - otherwise you're going to have to fork your logic at some point to account for either a numeric or string value.  Right now the system attempts a direct cast to string, which fails if the source data is not a string type, since casting does not implicitly call ToString to convert values to strings.
However, one workaround to try is to use object as the field type, then convert the value to decimal outside of the raw data layer. You can dynamically do that by using Convert.ChangeType(val, typeof(decimal)) which will either take a decimal value as-is or parse the string value at runtime. Using object does bring boxing (storing a primitive value as a reference) into play, but you'll have to decide whether the possible performance hit is significant enough to change the raw data layer so you can use decimal natively.

I am working with our database engineer to alter the procedure instead, it is the most logical solution rather than jumping through hoops on my end to do the conversions. I appreciate the suggestion though, definitely another tool in the belt.
